# Json call making in android

Tags: android, json

I am new bee in Android , so the knowledge regarding android is not so vast.

I am trying to implement Json call in android and i am using the foolowing code to get the list of all the contacts in the database.

```
package com.example.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {



    Button show_data;
    JSONObject my_json_obj;
    String path,firstname,lastname;
    {
    path = "http://192.168.71.129:3000/contacts";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
        HttpEntity  entity;
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlconn;
        my_json_obj = new JSONObject();

    }
}
```

I dont know if this is the right method but this code was already existing in another project and i have just made some change.

Please guide me through this one as i have gone through many stackoverflow and google answers,but it is very confusing as i am just a beginner and dont have knowledge of json calls in android.

Comment: refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Please use camelCase for your variables, it's how it's done in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could give you a chunk of code and say "*Hey try this*", but like you stated that you are very new to Android so I simply wont.
I think its of more value that you can learn something beter by trying then simply copy pasting code(most of the time)

There are a couple of things you need to consider when you do network request and parsing data.

Network request you must always do this in a seperate thread then the UI thread, because if you dont youll get a *NetworkOnMainUiThreadException* if I am correct out the top of my head.

The same applies for parsing the data you have retrieved from your request.
I dont see any parsing of data in your current code but I just wanted to give you a headsup because you will prob do this at some point in your application.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you can find a tutorial how to do threading with the AsyncTask. this is "the way" how it should be done in Android, they realy made it easy for you.

When reading that tutorial you will get the basic knowlage to do stuff in this class.

When you get the concept of threading and how to work with this newly added skill I would suggest reading and following up on this **json** tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html).

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this, result variable has your responce

```
try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("paset_your_url_here");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);  

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line + NL);
        }

        in.close();
          result = sb.toString();
          Log.i("", "-----------------------"+result);


    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

if you want to prase json then first do googling and if you get your answer by this then vote up :)